# Weird fluid motion

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Suppose I filled a bucket of water with a hose, now when it's filled, I remove the hose from the tap's end, while the other end is still submerged in water. Now if I throw the other end on the ground, it sucks all the water from inside the bucket spilling it out the ground till it's empty. Why does this happen?

I assume there's something really simple about pressure and stuff going on which someone like me, who hasn't studied fluids in detail, can understand...

Answer (score 2):

You have formed a [siphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon).

In this instance, if the water at the highest point of the hose is not replaced as it falls down, it will leave an area of low pressure/vaccum which would in turn suck up more water from the bucket. This makes it so the flow is self-sustaining. This works as long as the open end of the hose is lower than the end in the reservoir, and as long as you get the hose flowing in that direction in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a siphon and there are two two theories regarding as to how a siphon works.

The first is that a pressure difference is created between the low pressure at the inlet due to liquid being sucked away from that region and the higher atmospheric pressure acting on the liquid surface which then pushes the liquid through the siphon.
This theory was found not to be completely satisfactory when it was found that siphons work when the atmospheric pressure is very low, [Can a Siphon Work In Vacuo?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8F4i9M3y0ew) and also are able to raise the liquid to a greater distance than one would expect with the ambient atmospheric pressure, [Negative Pressures and the First Water Siphon Taller than 10.33 Meters](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4824372/).

Thus a second theory was proposed with the bonds between liquid molecules being so strong that the liquid acts like a falling chain and pulls the liquid through the siphon.
Again this theory is not the complete answer as gases can be siphoned, [Pouring and Siphoning a Gas](https://youtu.be/FWybQPxKy1U?si=m1GCZhQ9wUlCFxac&t=296).

There is much more in the Wikipedia article [siphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon).